# How do I add a path to the open_basedir in Plesk for all domains?

Tags: plesk

As the title says, how do I add a path to the open_basedir in Plesk for all domains?

I have to change the open_basedir value for all domains from:

```
{DOCROOT}/:/tmp/
```

to:

```
{DOCROOT}/:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/{DOMAIN?}/
```

I know where to do it, I just don't know what the variable is for the parent of {DOCROOT}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about Plesk 10.3, but in Plesk 10.4 there is {WEBSPACEROOT} which exposed to /var/www/vhosts/%domain-name%/. So, you just need to replace "{DOCROOT}/:/tmp/" to "{WEBSPACEROOT}/:/tmp/" in PHP settings of Service Plan.

And it's a default settings in Plesk 11.0.

For Plesk 10.0, for case when **php works as Apache module**:

```
mkdir /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/service/
cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/service/php.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/service/
```

in /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/service/php.php replace strings

```
echo "php_admin_value open_basedir {$OPT['dir']}/:/tmp/\n";
```

to

```
echo "php_admin_value open_basedir " . str_replace('/httpdocs', '', $OPT['dir']) . "/:/tmp/\n";
```

and run:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all # to apply new configuration for all domains
```

But for CGI and FastCGI there is need to change /var/www/vhosts/domain-name/etc/php.ini file and I don't know how deal with it.

Comment: yes - this is correct, I finally got an answer in the plesk forums. unfortunately I'm on plesk 10. [the rest of the post was "not possible"]

Answer (score 3):

I've used the Oleg's solution for php.php template at plesk 11 and just changed the following code:

```
echo $OPT['settings'];
```

to

```
echo str_replace(':/tmp/', ':/tmp/:/php/includes/', $OPT['settings']);
```

This is not a very robust solution as can made more option replaces than needed, but that works in common cases (adds /php/includes/ directory into open_basedir option).
Commonly those changes might be done via plesk service plan correction, but when you have too many domain with custom service plans - that might be a pain changing all the domain settings.

Comment: Plesk 11 users please find it here: http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/index.htm?fileName=69310.htm